# In my element type index view, why is the first column always empty?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I am creating a simple Element Type to hold form submissions, but I have hit a wall with this one issue I am having. For some reason I cannot get anything to output in the first column of my element type's index view. I have attached a screenshot. It doesn't matter what column comes first it is always blank. If I inspect the contents of the empty cells there is an empty anchor tag that links correctly to the edit/view entry template. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a great question. Required reading for anyone working with Element Types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first column is reserved for whatever your element model's `__toString()` function returns. By default that is the element's title, if your element type has editable titles. Otherwise you will need to override that method and return whatever makes sense.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!